# Can't Run Django Local Server due to Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, plotly-dash

I am trying to migrate my Django database after installing  django_plotly_dash and am receiving this error even though I have dash installed and working fine. Any ideas why this will not work when I try it with Django?

**Command:**

```
C:\Users\xxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Installing dash:
C:\Users\xxx>pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org dash
Requirement already satisfied: dash in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=1.0.2 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-compress in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dash_renderer==1.4.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-core-components==1.10.0 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-html-components==1.0.3 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-table==4.7.0 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (4.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from dash) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from flask-compress->dash) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: retrying>=1.3.3 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (1.3.3)
```

**Error:**

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .dash_wrapper import DjangoDash
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_plotly_dash\dash_wrapper.py", line 32, in <module>
    from dash import Dash
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dash' from 'dash' (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dash\__init__.py)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like where it installs Dash:

`c:\python38\lib\site-packages`

is not where it's looking for Dash:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Dash' from 'dash' (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dash\__init__.py)`

This looks like a Python pathname issue. It should work if you can either get it to install to the same place it's looking, or change where it's looking to the place where it's being installed.

Comment: Copy pasted my entire Dash folder to that location and it worked